# PayPal IPN does not reach. Retrying with no HTTP response code

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am facing a strange problem which started today. PayPal IPN are not reaching my site. Last 4 IPN are showing a 'Retrying' in IPN history but they do not have any HTTP response code. I checked my server log where I do not find any entry of these last 4 IPN. It was working fine till yesterday midnight. I have not make any changes in my server. I host Siteground also do not see any issues at the server end.

Can anyone please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: You may need to contact PayPal to find out why they aren't able to get a response from your server. What happens when you load the listener URL in a web browser, or test it using the IPN tester?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. It seems they don't have any technical support system. Their IPN support page redirects me to Stackoverflow to ask any technical questions. Call center only takes care of financial disputes.

Comment: There is a Contact Us / Contact technical support link.